# Derivatives of exp(f(x)) and partitions of an set

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, integer-partitions, multinomial-coefficients

I am trying to express the $k$-th derivative of $g(x) = exp(f(x))$ in a meaningful way. My logic got me so far.
For the first derivative, the result would be
$$
g' = f' g
$$
Second derivative would be
$$
g'' = (f'' + f'^2) g
$$
Third derivative is
$$
g''' = f''' + 3 f'' f' + f'^3
$$
and so on.

The correspondence that I made was that each derivative can be expressed as
$$
f ''' \equiv (0,0,3)
$$
$$
f'f'' = (0,1,2)
$$
and
$$
f'^3 \equiv (1, 1, 1).
$$
This is identical to representing the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of the integer 3. 
This is similar to the partitions of a set; a set of size 3, $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$, can be partitioned into
$$
\left\{a,b,c\right\} \equiv(0,0,3)
$$
$$
\left\{a\right\} \left\{b,c\right\}, \left\{b\right\} \left\{a,c\right\}, \left\{c\right\} \left\{a,b\right\} \equiv(0,1,2)
$$
$$
\left\{a\right\} \left\{b\right\}  \left\{c\right\} \equiv(1,1,1).
$$
The coefficient, for example, of $f'f''$, is the number of partitions corresponding to $(0,1,2)$. Then, I know that these coefficients can be calculated with the [help of multinomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490821/number-of-partitions-of-a-set-where-the-partitions-have-specific-sizes).

My question is: is there a proof of (or a reference about) this correspondence between the derivatives of $g$ and counting the number of partitions?

Comment: Have you tried induction? Seems like a reasonable idea here.

Comment: Yes it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might relate to the Butcher group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butcher_group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The paper *[Deriving Faa di Bruno’s formula for the derivative of a composite function via compositions of integers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.0519.pdf)* by Steffen Egger could be of interest to you.
>
> It derives the $n$th derivative of composite functions by means of *[partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%5C%28number_theory%5C%29)* resp. *[compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%5C%28combinatorics%5C%29)*, their ordered companions.

*Note:* If we consider an integer $n$ as (ordered) sum with $k$ parts
 $$n=\pi_1+2\pi_2+\cdots +k\pi_k$$ we can represent it as $k$-tuple
\begin{align*}
(\pi_1,\pi_2,\ldots,\pi_k)
\end{align*}
Similarly we can represent
\begin{align*}
f^{\prime\prime\prime} &\equiv (0,0,1)\\
f^{\prime}\cdot f^{\prime\prime}&\equiv (1,1,0)\\
\left(f^{\prime}\right)^3&\equiv (3,0,0)
\end{align*}