# Integer partitions appearing in the derivatives of $f(x) \log\left(f(x)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, derivatives

This topic has probably been already investigated before, if not, it suggests an interesting connection between **calculus** and **number theory**, in particular **integer partitions**.

Consider the function defined as $F(x) = f(x)\log\left(f(x)\right)$, where $\log$ is the natural logarithm. Now, take a look at its derivatives:

$$
\begin{align}
 F^{(1)}&=f'\log f+f' \\
 F^{(2)}&=f''\log f+f''+\frac{\left(f'\right)^2}{f} \\ 
 F^{(3)}&=f^{(3)}\log f+f^{(3)}-\frac{\left(f'\right)^3}{f^2}+3\frac{f'f''}{f} \\
 F^{(4)}&=f^{(4)}\log f+f^{(4)}+2\frac{\left(f'\right)^4} 
          {f^3}-6\frac{\left(f'\right)^2f''}{f^2}+3\frac{\left(f''\right)^2} 
          {f}+4\frac{f^{(3)}f'}{f} \\
 F^{(5)}&=f^{(5)}\log f+f^{(5)}-6\frac{\left(f'\right)^5}{f^4}+5\frac{f^{(4)}f'}{f}+10\frac{f^{(3)}f''}{f}-10\frac{f^{(3)}\left(f'\right)^2}{f^2}+20\frac{\left(f'\right)^3f''}{f^3}-15\frac{f'\left(f''\right)^2}{f^2} \\
\vdots
\end{align}
$$

As you can see, if we ignore the first term, where the logarithm appears, and the denominators of the fractions, for example by supposing there is an $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)=1$, then it seems that $F^{(n)}(x_0)$ has terms corresponding exactly to the *partitions* of $n$.
To see this, just sum up the orders of the derivatives that appear in each term *with multiplicity* given by their exponent, it will always result in exactly the order of the derivative you are looking at.

Moreover, this "correspondence" appears to be a "bijection", in the sense that

$$\text{If $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k)$ is a partition of $n$, then it appears in the expansion of $F^{(n)}(x_0)$} $$
All of these are still conjectures. I was only able to check this up to $n=10$ since Wolfram won't go any further in calculating the derivatives, but it seems true up to that point.

If the result holds, then, by referring with

- $p(n)=$ to the partition function, in other words the number of distinct partitions of $n$
- $\left| F(x) \right|$ to the "number of terms" in the expansion of $F$ (not very clear as a definition but it's the best I have)

Then the following **should** hold:
$$p(n) = \left|F^{(n)}(x_0)\right|$$

Now, to make it more rigorous, **is the following conjecture true?**

> If $F(x)=f(x)\log\left(f(x)\right)$, and $f(x_0)=1$, then
> $$ F^{(n)}(x_0) = \sum_{(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k) \text{partition of $n$}} C(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)\cdot f^{(\lambda_1)}(x_0)\cdot\dots\cdot f^{(\lambda_k)}(x_0) $$
> where the coefficients $C(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$ are non-zero integers.

I believe it is true, but can't see a way to prove it. Either there is something very obvious about how the terms in every derivative generate from the terms in the previous one and I'm missing it, or there is something more interesting going on.

Now, let us focus on the **coefficients** $C(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$, since they follow many non-trivial patterns.

In a way, $C(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$ can be interpreted as some kind of "weight" of the partition $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$. Unfortunately their value seems to be far from obvious, altough in some cases it *seems* to follow some patterns that I will show, but first, some notation:

I will denote the partition $n=\underbrace{a+\dots+a}_{c_a}+\underbrace{b+\dots+b}_{c_b}+\dots+\underbrace{m+\dots+m}_{c_m}$ as $(a\cdot c_a,b\cdot c_b,\dots,m\cdot c_m)$

Now, for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, some of the regularities that I spotted in the weights are the following:

- $C(n)=1$
- $C(1\cdot(n-k),k)=\frac{(-1)^{n-k-1}n!}{(n-k)k!}$ for $k$ up to $n-1$
- $C(n-k,k)=\binom{n}{k}$ EXCEPT when $n-k=n/2$, in that case this coefficient fails
- if $n=2k$, then $C(k\cdot2)=\frac12 \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$
- if $n=3k$, then $C(k\cdot3)=-\frac16 \frac{(3k)!}{(k!)^3}$
- if $n=\alpha\cdot k$, $\alpha\ge 4$, then $C(k\cdot\alpha)$ *appears* to be of the form $\frac{1}{c_{\alpha}}\frac{(\alpha k)!}{(k!)^{\alpha}}$ for some $c_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{N}$

As you can see, this are all pretty "easy" partitions, in the sense that they either have only two components or most of the components are the same. I couldn't find any regularity for more complicated partitions, and part of the reason was the number of partitions of $n$ grows exponentially as $\sqrt n$, so there are many cases to check.

However, I am interested in knowing if some kind of closed expression for $C(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$ exists, so **the second question** is:

> Given a partition of $n$ of the form $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$, is there a way to determine the value of its "weight" $C(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$, defined as the coefficient of the partition in the expansion of $F^{(n)}(x_0)$?

As an interesting final remark, notice that, if we set $f(x)=e^x$, and $x_0=0$, then, expanding $xe^x$ as a Taylor series, and assuming the conjecture holds true, we have that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum_{(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k) \text{partition of $n$}} C(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k) = n $$
which I think is quite nice.

Comment: I haven't fully read the question but thought you might want to look at the Faa di Bruno formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno's_formula

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2132224/305862).